# onclick doesn't go to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, image, struts-1

To display the Image doing as below.

```
<html:image alt="Calendar" 
            src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/abc.png" 
            onclick=javascript()>
</html:image>
```

When I'm opening the page in the browser I get an exception and src="" saying...
<%= was not terminated properly
Please help me on this and I'm sure that calling javascript function is correct.Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "Started in 2000, Struts 1 had its last release - version 1.3.10 - in December 2008." !! :O

Comment: There are no quotes around your `onclick`.

Comment: okay about quotes.Do you know the exception I'm getting ? <%= not terminated properly?

Comment: Did you look at the source code!  What is generated?

Comment: getContextPath() is the UI path

Comment: Did you look at the source code? What is generated?

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems at first glance:

1. The error you reference points towards your templating engine not working. I assume that the `<%=` characters should not be in the source code, once viewed on the client. Rather the html page should be processed before being sent to the client, and anything inside the tags replaced with the variable value being referenced. It seems something is broken there, and there is insufficient info in your question to debug that further.
2. Your onclick attribute is missing "quotes".

See below.

```
<html:image alt="Calendar" 
            src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/abc.png" 
            onclick="javascript()">
</html:image>
```